# How to add parameters to API calls?

Tags: parameters

I'm using CareerBuilder's API:

http://api.careerbuilder.com/Search/jobsearch/jobsearchinfo.aspx

In the description, the endpoint is:

http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch

As the developer key is necessary, I assume that the key should insert after v1 with a ?, as follows:

http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1?DeveloperKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/jobsearch

Then, if I put this into a browser, it should return me the XML as the output.

When I have done this, the page gave me 404 errors.

How does this type of API works? I assume it works like Google APIs

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solve this by adding parameters at the end of the endpoint URL...

http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch?DeveloperKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ID=YYYYY